# Help installing Caldera forms

Tags: wordpress, webform-civicrm, extension, forms, caldera-forms

So I am trying to figure out how to install the new community maintained fork of Caldera forms that was put in place to continue the end-of-life version (for WordPress CiviCRM ).

https://civicrm.org/blog/jaapjansma/community-maintained-fork-caldera-forms

It is unclear to me how I should proceed...

Do I need to install a Caldera Forms WordPress plugin first and then install a CiviCRM Caldera Forms extension?

When I go to https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/caldera-civicrm there is a dependencies folder and several other caldera folders.... which ones of these need to be installed (or maybe all of them)?

It talks about "building" or about using "composer" to install some of these... Is there a pre-built version that can just be uploaded/FTP firectly to /civicrm/civicrm/ext/ folder without having to get into all the fancy building/composing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to download one of the prebuilt zip files from https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/caldera-civicrm/caldera-forms/-/releases Do NOT use the links at the top of the page under 'Assets' but use one of the links at the bottom:

[image]

(Thanks to kcristiano: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/p1z3gpzadfn4pki5gsn4nsbu8o)

You only need one of those zips - they are basically the same although the 'caldera-forms-1.9.7-release.zip has a slightly later version of the monolog library.  That's the main 'Caldera Forms' plugin.

You also want one of the plugins to integrate CF with CiviCRM. Options include:

- [Caldera Forms CiviCRM](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/cf-civicrm/)
- [Integration of CiviCRM's Form Processor with Caldera Forms](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/cf-civicrm-formprocessor/)

If you use the second one, you also need a couple of other plugins/extensions - see its documentation.

Comment: Ok so the WP Repo is the WordPress plugin which I have succesfully uploaded and activated. But what do I do with the BUILT FROM THIS REPO caldera-froms-1.9.7-release.zip? I extracted the caldera-forms folder from the zip and uploaded it into /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/ folder, but it does not show up in the CiviCRM Administer Extensions menu.

Comment: I've updated the answer which hopefully clarifies things.